# Oracle SQL AND condition for DATE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How to query in oracle SQL for the AND condition from the below table.

I want to query like where Start_date =something AND End_date=something

```
ID   Start_date                       End_date                         STATUS            USER        
21  4/16/2010 11:00:00 PM          4/16/2010 11:59:00 PM               PENDING           TOM
22  4/18/2010 11:00:00 AM          4/18/2010 11:59:00 PM               COMPLETED         JACK
23  4/20/2010 11:00:00 PM          4/20/2010 11:59:00 PM               PENDING           JEFF
24  5/16/2010 11:00:00 PM          5/16/2010 11:59:00 PM               STARTED           MIKE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
where start_date = '4/16/2010 11:00:00 PM' and end_date = '4/16/2010 11:59:00 PM'
```

Comment: Unrelated but: using a string literal like `'4/16/2010 11:00:00 PM'` is not a safe thing to do. (e.g. it will not run on my computer). You should use `to_date()` to convert a string into a date or use an ANSI date literal.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ahh I actually didnt know that. After reading a bit, do you just write it like `= date '4/16/2010 11:00:00 PM'`? I dont use oracle sql very often.

Comment: An ANSI literal uses the ISO date/timestamp format: `timestamp '2010-04-16 23:00:00'` or `date '2015-01-24'`